# SharePoint REST API unread/mention count

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, social

I like to retrieve unread/mention count using REST API but I do not know how to begin?

Can anyone tell me how should I begin and do I need any credentials when consuming the REST service?

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke a REST call from C# Client Application or JavaScript

The REST call you are mentioning relates to Social Feature and more on this is explained in msdn

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn155789.aspx#bk_myUnreadMentionCount

The endpoint is `<siteUri>/_api/social.feed/my/UnreadMentionCount`

If you are making these REST calls from within SharePoint then you don't need to pass any credentials.

Comment: Is there a compact overview of which endpoints are available after ``/_api/`` ?

Comment: MSDN has all the details.. here is the top documentation section https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142380.aspx

Comment: @AmalHashim I tried with XML.Document opened, however it return me a unauthorize 401 error. I am invoking at C# backend part. any advise?

Comment: What about view all of them and not just the count?